# Magento costum module shows 404

Tags: magento, module, http-status-code-404

I tried the tutorial on http://www.satollo.net/magento-pdf-invoices-customer-dashboard/comment-page-1#comment-47565.

This allows a user to view invoices as PDF on the frontend of my Magento store. The problem is, when I click on the link which points to `Pdfinvoice/index/invoices/order_id/5/` it shows a 404 error.

I registered the module as followed:
(renamed to module to `Pdfinvoice` to avoid conflict with another module)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Pdfinvoice>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Pdfinvoice>
</modules>
 </config>
```

`app/etc/modules/Pdfinvoice.xml`

I am breaking my head over this.
Maybe the module isn't registered? I've tried googling it, but I can't get it to work.

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Comment: The problem is not in your module registration. It is probbably related to an error in config.xml (routers tag part), controller class implementation or simply you entering the wrong url. I'd say that you forgot to rename something in config.xml after renaming the module.

Comment: Why are you coding directly under a namespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you rename the module in the module definition xml, make sure you do the same with your local folder (app/code/local/Pdfinvoice), your config.xml:

app/code/local/Pdfinvoice/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Pdfinvoice>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Pdfinvoice>
</modules>

<frontend>
    <routers>
        <pdf>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Pdfinvoice</module>
                <frontName>pdfinvoice</frontName>
            </args>
        </pdf>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

.. and your new controller:

app/code/local/Pdfinvoice/controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php
class Pdfinvoice_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

public function invoicesAction() {
...
```

Works flawless, I installed the module in minutes.

Comment: I triple checked everthing bud is doenst work. Uploaded the file to http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57375995/pdf_as_invoice.rar. can you find the problem?

Comment: i found two issues: in the template file _$this->getUrl('Pdf/index/invoices', array('order_id' => $_order->getId()))_ pleaase with lowercase "Pdf", and in etc/config.xml it is better to have a closing _</config>_ tag

Comment: If the answer was helpful, please click accept [link to faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask). Thank you.